# App rejection clarification - HELP on what the actual issue is?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, appstore-approval

I submitted my fantasy football app for the first time and got rejected for the following reason,

> "12.3: Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a
>   collection of links, may be rejected - We found that the experience
>   your app provides is not sufficiently different from browsing a
>   content or link aggregator web site, as required by the App Store
>   Review Guidelines. While your app may facilitate access to web sites
>   or to content from a range of web sites, even when including features
>   such as Push Notifications, the experience it provides is not
>   significantly different from using Safari. Such apps do not include
>   enough native iOS functionality to be appropriate for the App Store.
>   We encourage you to review your app concept and evaluate whether you
>   can incorporate additional features to enhance the user experience."

So, I added some new features, including social media sharing and player tracking functionality in order for the users to search/select multiple players and see those favorite players highlighted throughout the app. I then resubmitted the app and got rejected again for the following reason,

> "10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined,
>   creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are
>   worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or
>   less than very good it may be rejected. We found the user interface of
>   your app is not of sufficient quality to be appropriate for the App
>   Store. Apps that provide a poor user experience are not in compliance
>   with the App Store Review Guidelines. Rejected for violating guideline
>   10.6 The app provides a poor user experience as it consists of feeds aggregated from www.fantasyfootballfreaks.com and contains a poor UI.
>   Please evaluate whether you can make the necessary revisions to
>   improve the user experience of your app. Keep in mind that Apple and
>   Apple customers place a high value - and have high standards - on the
>   user interface and the experience an app provides. Apps should be
>   engaging and exciting, enabling users to do something they couldn't do
>   before; or to do something in a way they couldn't do before or better
>   than they could do it before. And apps should be specific to the iOS
>   platform to take the fullest advantage of iOS in delivering a robust
>   user experience."

I've contacted Apple and haven't received any feedback yet. I'm confused on what I should be working on to update the app and resubmit it again. Ultimately, what is their concern? Is it the pulling of information from our web server? Was the added functionality enough, but now they don't like the UI now (if so, why)? The app is universal for iPhone and iPad and they only included screenshots of the iPad in the 2nd rejection as a reference. I don't get the "poor UI" issue, since the screenshots reference two table views where I display an image, title and description of articles and news items. It's very simple, straightforward and easy to read for the users. They also included my player tracking view where I allow the user to select their favorite players, they can search, scroll or click on the team labels on the right side (very easy and user friendly).

I've looked at many general news and fantasy football apps, and they all implement very similar table views and scroll views to display their data which is being pulled from their web servers too. Is it just because my company name isn't yahoo or espn? I don't use any webviews within my app either. We have thousands of users that would like to get their hands on the app, but I don't know what the really issue is that I need to fix.

Any recommendations or feedback from your experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. The football season has already started and I'm way behind schedule because of the rejections.

http://www.fantasyfootballfreaks.com/app.php

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your app.

Comment: See link in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Why not working on improving the web site for mobile's browsers?

On this way it wouldn't be restricted to iOS devices, and Apple's review wouldn't be  necessary. 


For me, apps that don't use mobile's capabilities e.g., location, camera, mic, are better as webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apps should be engaging and exciting, enabling users to do something
>   they couldn't do before; or to do something in a way they couldn't do
>   before or better than they could do it before. And apps should be
>   **specific to the iOS platform to take the fullest advantage** of iOS in
>   delivering a robust user experience.

and

> The app is universal for iPhone and iPad and they only included
>   screenshots of the iPad in the 2nd rejection as a reference.

you wrote.

> I don't get the "poor UI" issue

Sad... just look above once again it is there.

I would make iPhone, iPhone Retina, iPad, iPad Retina version design at least.

Ofc the "universal" Phonegap, Appcelarator like generated app look like trash. 
Try to embed some noce images as desing, for splash, app icon, tabs, buttons and so on.
Maybe you need adesigner work too, not the plain sdk generated buttons.

Edit
adding screenshot as it would be in new iPad ( retina ) 
[image: screenshot]

That has a serious reason to reject it! Tipp: Try to release **only** for iPhone if you have small images and you don't want dynamic thumbnail image size. But you set up as Universal, so from iPhone 3 to new iPad resolutions all!!!

If you do a news grabber, than resize the images as it looks clear.
+ need design work in buttons, table, table cell, backgrounds and so on.

Comment: Hi matheszabi, I added a link to my original post with the screenshots they included. I did create multiple image sizes for most images across iphone and iPad, BUT you are right it looks like for the tableview thumbnail size image I am using the smaller sized image for both the iphone and iPad. Do you believe that is the main/only issue they have with the app now? Thanks.

Comment: @rossi Hey, as I have expected the is no design work on you app. Plus the new iPad has 2048-by-1536 resolution, try to open your link and zoom it, if you don't have an ipad, you will see how ugly are the thumbnail images ( horrible ) . Table, Table cells, buttons need desing, that app is good for school, not for Appstore. If you think my post is usefull ( even you don't like it) vote up pls :)

Comment: thanks for the information. How do I go about optimizing for dynamic thumbnail image sizes, outside of checking if on iPhone vs ipad and displaying a different image (so if iphone image is 90x60, create an ipad one at 180x120?). I was trying to keep the table, table cells, background, etc simple and easy to read. Any recommendations on how to update the design to make it more Appstore ready?

Comment: you can open another question ( but I suggest to google it) how to retrieve if is iPad or it is iPhone, it is Retina or it isn't. Send those 2 variables to your server and the server will send to you 4 different size of thumbnails based on that info + put design for button .

Answer (score 0):

I hope your app is a football game, apple team evaluate your app and if found similar to some other app or if you use low quality images which is not so crisp in Retina display , they will reject because apple is so concerned about the following things.

1. Quality of graphics.
2. No similarity to other app.
3. Your code is not effective.

the preceding are general principal, besides i don't know how good your app is if possible post screenshot..

Regards.

Comment: See link in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they either don't realise that you own the web page and think that you just pull the data from some website you found on the web or they are unhappy that you just have a blown up table in each tab. Maybe if you used a split view (with a narrow table on the left and detail view in the middle) they would consider the UI sufficiently iPad-like?